# UICollectionView `reloadData` causes UILabel lines to disappear

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uilabel, reloaddata

I have a `UILabel` in a `collectionView` header. The label is set to zero lines, word wrapping, and proper leading/trailing/top space constraints. If i DO NOT call `[collectionView reloadData]`, the label expands properly to text with greater than two lines. Once `reloadData` is called, the label goes back to a single line...the second line disappears.

```
 - (UICollectionReusableView *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
        header = (viewRollHeader *) [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"header" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        header.rollTitle.text = [self.roll objectForKey:@"title"];
        header.rollDescription.text = [self.roll objectForKey:@"info"];

        [header.cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(exit) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        return header;
   }
   return [UICollectionReusableView new];
}


- (CGSize) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if (section == 0) {
        CGRect labelRect = [[self.roll objectForKey:@"title"]
                        boundingRectWithSize: header.rollTitle.frame.size
                        options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                        attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:32.0f]}
                        context:nil];
        return CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width, (174.0f + labelRect.size.height));
    }
    return CGSizeZero;
}
```

Comment: Post the code please.

Comment: @Ismail it's done in storyboard. Only code is reloadData

Comment: how can you handle everything for `UICollectionView` in storyboard??? Where is the dataSource/ delegate methods?

Comment: @Ismail Here are my header methods.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

`collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:` is used for the header or footer of the *entire* collectionView, while `collectionView:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:` is used for the header of a specific *section* of the collectionView

to make sure the size of the header stays consistent and respects your constraints, you'll need to call `[(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout setHeaderReferenceSize:CGSizeMake(width, height)]` once the flowlayout is instantiated

Comment: Label still goes back to one line after reloadData. It must be something with the constraints.

Comment: curious - is it the `@"title"` or `@"info"` you're meaning to base the label rect off of? also, what does `174.0f` reference?

Comment: @adulfo The `174.0f` is the original height of the header. First, Im trying to expand the height to the `rollTitle` So I return the original header height + the height of the label expanded to `@"title"`

Comment: @Peter I'm not sure what's causing the issue. My instinct would be to place a breakpoint where you're creating the `labelRect` and check `header.rollTitle.frame.size` to see what's being handed `boundingRectWithSize`

Comment: Also without calling `reloadData` and simply scrolling the `collectionView` the three lined label goes back to one. Not sure if this gives you a flag to a different potential issue.

Comment: @Peter do you have a certain height being set within `prepareForReuse` or `awakeFromNib` by chance?

Answer (score 0):

Use label setter property inside delegate method where you configure each cell.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
//add label property here
    return cell;
}
```

After reloading, it calls this method again to configure the label.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the preferredMaxLayoutWidth to the label

```
self.label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 300;
```